# Multiple request pools with node.js request module

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I'm using the node.js request module to fetch the contents of URLs.  it works great, and I can even pass in `maxSockets: XXX` to have it do more in parallel.

However, I have a few places in my code where I need to do different requests to different places. I'd like to be able to create two separate pools of 25 requests at a time, etc.  However, the request module doesn't seem set up to have a constructor to create different pools.

Suggestions for the how I might go about this?

I'd ideally like something along the following lines:

```
var r1 = new request({ maxSockets: 25 });
var r2 = new request({ maxSockets: 25 });
```

and then just start using them both for fetching stuff …

Any suggestions how to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I get your question right - maybe because I've never used the request module.

But, by reading [the module README](https://npmjs.org/package/request), I think you could, in some file of your project, export a function which defaults some options for you.
Somewhat like this:

```
function createRequest( url, callback ) {
  return request({
    pool: { maxSockets: 25 },
    // Maybe more things here
    url: url
  }, callback );
}
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, what I understand about node.js namespaces, however, is that since they're just referring to the same require()d module, they'll all get the same object (module) instance, yes? I want separate object instances and pools.

Comment: Node only caches the evaluated file exports when you do `require()`; so, in your case, the request module is exporting a function. This function will create everything internally when you call it. When you export a single object for example, like a configuration-only file, then you should be careful; probably wrapping it in a function would be better. Hope I clarified things for you now :)